# Cant use libcurl async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, libcurl

Using curl_easy, I download files wrapped in std::async.
3 asynchronous requests have been created, but a problem arises when one of the requests stumbles upon a large file and starts downloading it, the whole program hangs from this. It turns out that asynchronous requests are completely non-asynchronous.

```
using namespace std;

int allGameFileCount = 10000; // The count of files are written here
string allGameFiles[10000] = {}; // The file names are written here

bool downloadFile(const char* filename, const char* out)
{
    CURL* curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen(out, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWriteToFile);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        long httpStatusCode = 0;
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpStatusCode);
        if (result == CURLE_OK && httpStatusCode == 200)
        {
            // Success
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            fclose(fp);
            return true;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return false;
}

int main() {
       future<void> f1 = async(launch::async, [] {
        if (downloadGameFile(allGameFiles[allGameFileCount].c_str(), allGameFiles[allGameFileCount].c_str()))
        {
          allGameFiles[allGameFileCount] = "";
          allGameFileCount--;
        }});

       future<void> f2 = async(launch::async, [] {
        if (downloadGameFile(allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-1].c_str(), allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-1].c_str()))
        {
          allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-1] = "";
          allGameFileCount--;
        }});

       future<void> f3 = async(launch::async, [] {
        if (downloadGameFile(allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-2].c_str(), allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-2].c_str()))
        {
          allGameFiles[allGameFileCount-2] = "";
          allGameFileCount--;
        }});
}
```

Comment: Show how you are using `std::async`.  WIthout involving CURL, you could replace your `downloadFile` function with something that sleeps for 20 seconds or something.  If your whole program still hangs, the problem is more likely to do with how you're joining async calls.

Comment: @paddy it still hangs

Comment: This has undefined behavior, if the first `async` to start executing is `f1` -- that accesses your array out of bounds.  There is no synchronization of the global counter so you have data races everywhere which means more undefined behavior.  You're better off capturing the appropriate counter value in the lambda.  Not saying this is _the_ issue, but based on the code you showed it _an_ issue.

Comment: Reading the documentation for [curl_easy_init](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html) there's another issue, which is that you do not call `curl_global_init` in your `main` function.  According to the docs: _"This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since curl_global_init is not thread-safe"_

Comment: Don't you need `f1.get()`, `f2.get()` and `f3.get()` before you exit `main`?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? The `std::future` descructor waits for the async operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are accessing the `allGameFiles` array out or range:

```cpp
int allGameFileCount = 10000; // The count of files are written here
string allGameFiles[10000] = {}; // The file names are written here
// ...
allGameFiles[allGameFileCount]
```

That is an Undefined Behavior, and that itself may cause an issue. You even assing a new value to the element outside of the range: one more reason to experience UB.

Next, you are trying to get `c_str()` out of an invalid object, and that is another reason of UB.

Finally you are assigning an empty string to some items in the array, but the index is being changed from different threads. That means that you may assign the value to the same element from different threads, and that is not safe.

One more reason for UB is the decrement of the same variable from different threads:

```cpp
allGameFileCount--;
```

You should use atomics instead.

There may be other issues, but fix these ones first, and your problem would probably disappear.

Comment: Tell me how to make array iteration on async safe?

Comment: You need to synchronize the access, but that is a huge topic to discuss in one comment. However even better is to make the data immutable. Instead of reusing the same variable `allGameFileCount` and changing it from different threads you can capture their own values in lambdas.